# Obtain standard deviation from sum of values

Tags: statistics, means, standard-deviation

I'm looking for a way to obtain the "composed" mean and standard deviation of two (related) datasets. So let's assume I have n = 25 recordings of one characteristic (x) and the same number of recordings for a distinct characteristic (y) with
$$
\mu_x = 15, SD_x=2.5;
\mu_y = 25, SD_y=3.5
$$

And furthermore let's assume that both characteristics may be added to a "composed" value with:
$$\mu_{xy} = (15+25)/2 = 20$$

Is there any way to find out what the SD for both would be? I think neither the pooled SD as described somewhere else is correct nor (e.g., [O'Neill 2014](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2014.966589), p. 283) with

$$s_{\text{pooled}}^2 = \frac{n_1-1}{n_1+n_2-1} \cdot s_1^2 + \frac{n_2-1}{n_1+n_2-1} \cdot s_2^2 + \frac{n_1 n_2}{n_1 + n_2} \cdot (\bar{x}_1 - \bar{x}_2)^2.$$

seems right to me. Are there any suggestions? There is no way to find out what the correlation between both is.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since, for each separate data set $Z$ we have $\sigma_Z^2=E[Z^2]-\mu_Z^2$ you can use the data from the two original ones to compute the variance of the merged set.

Comment: [Here](https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/basic-statistics/combined-variance.html) is the resulting formula (note that this expression allows the two original data sets to have different numbers of elements).

Comment: Thanks, that was quick!

Comment: After thinking a bit I guess my question was incorrect. Let's stick to an example similar to the one provided in the link. Let's assume a group of people earns an amount of 1000units monthly on average with a S.D. of 200 and additionally a variable income of of 250 unit with an S.D of 80. I there any formula get the variance (and S.D.) for the total amount of 1250 units on average (that is 1000 + 250 unit)?

Comment: Ah, no.  That's harder.  It's harder because one imagines that the two numbers (core income, variable income) are strongly correlated.  Absent information on the dependence, there is not much you can say.